# Job title for someone who design and integrate physical products and ux research

Tags: usability, interaction-design, user-research, user-centered-design, ux-integration

What would be the job title for someone who design prototypes of the physical products, and also be able to modify/integrate existing hardware and software (ex. experimenting with arduino?) to make it more user friendly with the ux research skills?

For example, I saw this recent product where they build the braille smart watch for visually impaired people. What is interesting here is that they used existing technologies and simply integrated them(Braille and watch) together to build a new product user-friendly for blind people. This is something I really want to learn and do.

Also, Which graduate school programs would fit for my interests? (Either in US or Canada) I'm a recent graduate with major in Psychology with a bit knowledge of programming language.

Thank you

Comment: Someone who is experienced in this field is Jason Mesut. He is a industrial designer who made the leap to interaction design: https://twitter.com/jasonmesut?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor

Answer (score 2):

It could be any or any combination of:

- industrial designer
- UX designer
- human factors interface designer
- product designer
- inventor
- engineer
- computer science
- (and I'm sure many more)

There's no one specific graduate program for this. It will really come down to finding one that you feel simply fits what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

**Industrial Designer** develops concepts and designs for manufactured products. They typically specialize in one product category, such as automobiles, furniture or housewares. They must be imaginative and persistent to communicate their ideas about new product design. [(Source)](http://study.com/what_does_an_industrial_designer_do.html)

**Hardware interface designers** draw upon industrial design, interaction design and electrical engineering. [(Source)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_interface_design)

I think what you're looking for is someone between these two roles or someone having the skillset of both.

Answer (score 0):

That still sounds like UX to me.

User Experience design is **not** user interface design (though that is the most commonly visible part of the job).

User Experience is a very broad specialty that covers the whole of a user's experience, the hardware very definitely is a key part of this, especially if you are to be using abnormal hardware.

I can recall several classes from my HCI masters where we looked at things like physical bank machines, little gizmos for old people to remind them to take their pills, etc...

The focus is the **user**, not what appears on a computer screen. Hardware and software are purely the tools that a UX Designer uses in order to help the user to do what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

The best known example is probably Jonathan Ive - currently in charge of design at Apple

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_Ive

Ive studied Industrial Design initially.

Industrial Design is understanding both the user - but also manufacturing processes and the properties of materials.